# trigonometry equation calculation

Tags: trigonometry

> Calculate
>   $$\frac{6 \sin(A) \sin (B) \cdot \sin (C)+\cos(A)\cdot \cos(B) \cdot \cos C)} { \cos(A+B) \cdot \cos(B+C) \cdot \cos(A+C)}$$
>   where $A+B+C=81$ and $\tan81=6$.

I have tried all of this question but it doesn’t work. Could you please give me some clue?

Comment: $$\tan(81)=6$$? What does it mean?

Comment: tan81degree is equal to 6

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It would be helpful if you could share the attempt that you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: $\tan(81^\circ)\neq6$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(81)&assumption=%22TrigRD%22+-%3E+%22D%22

Comment: If I replace $6$ by $\tan(81^\circ)$ in the formula, computer experiments give a constant value of $6.392453221499659=\sec(81^\circ)$  Could this be what is intended?

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS:**

First suppose $A=B=0,\, C=81^\circ.$  Substituting into the given formula gives $\sec(81^\circ)$, so apparently, this is what you have to prove.  Now, I did some computer experiments, and if I leave $6$ in the formula, I don't get a constant value, but if I replace $6$ by $\tan(81^\circ)$ then I do.  Therefore, it appears that what we have to prove is that $$
{\tan(A+B+C)\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}+\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}\over\cos(A+B)\cos(B+C)\cos(C+A)}={1\over\cos(A+B+C)}$$

Cross-multiply and use the addition formulas to see if you can verify this.

**EDIT**

Calculation with sympy confirms that the formula is true.  Good luck.

**P.S.**

If you know some calculus, a rather easy way to do this is to note that we need to prove $$F(A,B,C)\equiv0,$$
where $$
F(A,B,C) = \sin(A+B+C)\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}+\cos(A+B+C)\cos{B}\cos{C}-\\\cos(A+B)\cos(B+C)\cos(C+A)$$

It's straightforward to compute ${\partial F\over\partial A}=0,$ which means that the value doesn't depend on $A$, so we need only verify $F(A,B,C)=)$ for one value of $A$.  This is trivial when we set $A=0.$  (If you aren't acquainted with partial derivatives yet, it just means we treat $B$ and $C$ as constants for the moment, and differentiate with respect to $A$.)